# find max of timestamp in a list of objects in a document mongoDB springboot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework

I have a situation where I need to fetch a object in a list from mongo document by max of timestamp.
Below is one of the document in collection.

```
{
    "_id": "e7180b1c-fb58-41f5-9de6-8cfd4c707778",
    "audits": [
        {
            "_id": "e7180b1c-fb58-41f5-9de6-8cfd4c707778",
            "logId": "e7180vgc-fb58-41f5-9de6-8cfd4c707773",
            "status": "message Process Started",
            "hasErrors": false,
            "allStatuses": [
                {
                    "status": "message Listened",
                    "timestamp": {
                        "$date": "2021-01-05T08:29:55.000Z"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "status": "message Process Started",
                    "timestamp": {
                        "$date": "2021-01-05T09:29:55.000Z"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "timestamp": {
                "$date": "2021-01-05T09:29:55.000Z"
            },
            "error": null
        },
        {
            "_id": "e7180b1c-fb58-41f5-9de6-8cfd4c707778",
            "logId": "e7180vgc-fb58-41f5-9de6-8cfd4c707774",
            "status": "message Process Started",
            "hasErrors": false,
            "allStatuses": [
                {
                    "status": "message Listened",
                    "timestamp": {
                        "$date": "2021-01-05T09:29:55.000Z"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "status": "message Process Started",
                    "timestamp": {
                        "$date": "2021-01-05T12:29:55.000Z"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "timestamp": {
                "$date": "2021-01-05T12:29:55.000Z"
            },
            "error": null
        }
    ],
    "timestamp": {
        "$date": "2021-03-17T11:58:47.933Z"
    }
}
```

here I need to fetch object in audits where its timestamp is max, e.g. need object alone where audits.timestamp is max

Eg Output:

```
{
            "_id": "e7180b1c-fb58-41f5-9de6-8cfd4c707778",
            "logId": "e7180vgc-fb58-41f5-9de6-8cfd4c707774",
            "status": "message Process Started",
            "hasErrors": false,
            "allStatuses": [
                {
                    "status": "message Listened",
                    "timestamp": {
                        "$date": "2021-01-05T09:29:55.000Z"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "status": "message Process Started",
                    "timestamp": {
                        "$date": "2021-01-05T12:29:55.000Z"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "timestamp": {
                "$date": "2021-01-05T12:29:55.000Z"
            },
            "error": null
        }
```

Need code snippet for spring mongo aggregations.
Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry not aware of spring-mongo but this is the basic query you need:

```js
db.yourCollectionName.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$audits" },
    {
        $sort: {
            "audits.timestamp": -1
        }
    },
    { $limit: 1 },
    {
        $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$audits" }
    }
]);
```

Comment: I dont need a whole document, I just need a specific object in my list in document.